# Mysql 5.6 on centos 6.9, ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I did install mysql5.6 on Centos6.9 and I tried to grep for the temp password using this command,
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log, but nothing is returned. so I started the msql with  " sudo service mysqld start --skip-grant-tables" and followed below commands

Connect to MySQL via command line client: mysql -u root
Run query to update root user password, using command line MySQL client (which is connected in previous step):
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
Run another query to save changes to password: FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Type command to quit command line MySQL client: \q
Restart MySQL server: service mysqld restart

tried to connect to Mysql "mysql -u root -p" and I see this error

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

(I have to build this is centos6.9 nad upgrade the mysql 8.x, as our current setups are using centos6.9.)

Please help me fix this and thanks in advance.

I want to connect to mysql database so I can import the mysqldump and start the upgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

Foud a file that had secret root password, /root/.mysql_secret      [root@mysql56-2 ~]#  cat /root/.mysql_secret

## The random password set for the root user at Fri Jul 21 23:46:49 2023 (local time): tlGQrbJrGaPYwefwe

I was able to login with this password, but still not sure why I couldn't reset the root passwoord.